# How to pass data from card to new page in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to pass the data from card to new page,the data has two names START and at below STOP on card.When the user clicks on card the "START" data should pass to new page.Below is the code

```
class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("List"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0,top: 20.0,right: 5.0),
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){

              },
              child: new Card(
                child:
                new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text('START'),
                    new Text('STOP')
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

> New page

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("New page"),
      ),
      body:Container(
child:Center(
new Text('textview'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new page `MyHomePage` should accept the required inputs as arguments, like

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String startText;
  final String stopText;
  MyHomePage(this.startText, this.stopText);
  ....
}
.....
```

`onTap` should create new instance of MyHomePage with this data and launch the page like

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MyHomePage("start", "stop"),
      ),
    );
```